# I am not getting unique column using hibernate , for postgresql db

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
@Entity

@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"catgoryId","applcationNo"})})
```

I tried this explicitly @table

and unique , //but not getting result.

```
public class DmsDocDetailPojo {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long dmsDocId;

    @Column
    private String stateCode="AI";

    @Column(name = "applicationNo", unique = true,nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    private String applcationNo;

    @Column(name = "catgoryId", unique = true,nullable=false)
    private String catgoryId;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column( nullable = false, updatable=false)
    private Date doc_uploaded_dt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date doc_updated_dt;


    @Column(name = "document_file", columnDefinition = "BYTEA")
    private byte[] document_file;

    @Column
    private String fileName;

    @Column
    private Integer fileSize;

}
```

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: I am getting duplicate values inserted in db.

Comment: Is your table created by spring, or you created it manually?

Comment: Does your entity contains hashcode and equals and keep in mind not to include the surrogate key in methods.As comparison should be done on other attributes of entity

Answer (score 0):

check your database primary key it should be an auto increment